# Using Excel INDIRECT or another function to reference cell with sheet name that is in a dated format (dd mmm yyyy) to display chosen sheet cell data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a register of all sheets (tabs) within the workbook which displays the sheet name and the sheets title.

The problem I am having is that the sheet name is created using VBA from a master template and populates the sheet name as a date (04 Jun 2018) which is exactly what I need. The problem comes when I try to use something like `=INDIRECT("'"&C12&"'!B11")` to look up the sheets title in cell `B11`, it seems to struggle with the date format defaulting to (04/06/2018) resulting in `#REF!`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60096&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function to format the date. Note that the text format seems to be locale sensitive. Try `=INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(C12,"dd mmm yyyy") & "'!B11")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply format C12 according to your need:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(C12, "dd mmm yyyy")&"'!B11")
```